# How to get driving distance without km in google map api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am getting driving distance from google map api v3 using this code.

```
distance11 = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;
```

The code is working fine, but the output is coming in the format 300km. I need only the number 300. Please help me find a solution.

I already tried putting distance.value and simply distance but it didn't work.

Edit:.....

Also please tell me how to remove string from a variable using javascript. For instance getting only 300 from 300km.

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html#substring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular case, you can try

```
parseInt(distance11);
```

`parseInt` automatically removes the trailing string after the number. But if you know already that `distance11` ends with `"km"`, you can also do

```
distance11.slice(0, -2);
```

Comment: If it worked, you can accept my answer. Or you can have a try with geocodezip's answer, using `response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value` instead.

Comment: Beware that it wont always be km. Can be other units tool, in particullar meters, if it a short route. Can also be numbers like 67.5km which is why .value is definitly the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Distance), the distance service returns both the text (which you are trying to use) and a number in meters.

If you want other units than meters, you can convert it.